# Trying to return value from firebase querysnaphsot completion handler inside function

Tags: swift, asynchronous, completionhandler

I'm trying to return a value produced from an asynchronous block of code (from my completion handler) for my function `validateFields()`, however I'm not sure how to do that.

```
func validateFields() -> Bool
{
        //Other else if statements
        //...

        else if !(usernameTextField.text!.isEmpty)
        {
            var retVal = false
            
            isUnique { (bool) in
                retVal = bool
            }
            
            print("THIS IS THE RET VALUE: " + String(retVal))
            //this print statement does not return the correct value            

            if retVal == false { return retVal }
        }
        errorLabel.text = " "
        return true

}
```

As you can see, it doesn't work, I need to return `bool` in `isUnique` for my entire function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't store the result of `isUnique`'s closure then instantly return it, because `isUnique` will take as long as it takes to complete whatever task that is.

You want something like the following, where `completion` is called on **all** paths, but only once:

```
func validateFields(completion: (Bool) -> Void) {
    //Other else if statements
    //...
    if ... {
        /* ... */
    } else if !(usernameTextField.text!.isEmpty) {
        var retVal = false

        isUnique { (bool) in
            print("THIS IS THE RET VALUE: " + String(bool))
            completion(bool)
        }
    } else {
        errorLabel.text = " "
        completion(true)
    }
}
```

Caller:

```
validateFields { result in
    print("result: \(result)")
}
```

Comment: So there’s no possible way for me to wait until the code in isUnique finishes, before returning a Boolean?

Comment: @EAO123 Unless you want to use Swift 5.5 concurrency - no. You can’t return asynchronous values synchronously

Comment: How would I change my code to do that with Swift 5.5 concurrency

Comment: @EAO123 You would need to support only iOS 15+, for a start which may not be possible. Either way - the async/await in Swift 5.5 is functionally equivalent to this answer above. You’ll have to Google some resources or watch WWDC sessions to learn how to use it, but this answer above does exactly what you are looking for. There is no way around not being able to return values when you don’t know how long something takes, without the return value being in an asynchronous context again.

Comment: Ah, I see. I figured out, however, how to use `isUnique` without needing to return its value inside a function, so thank you!